# SQL SET settings when using Flyway

Tags: sql-server, flyway

When generating MS SQL scripts for DB migration, there are often `SET` commands at the top, such as

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
GO
```

Since any migration script can run depending the the current database migration version, presumably each script need to have this "header".

Is there a better way to approach this? 
Can these settings run once at every migration so that every script file don't have to contain it?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you have to try it with callback scripts. Read about it [here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/callbacks.html).

So you han have a script called `beforeMigrate.sql` within migration script directory and move this common settings in it. They have to be executed before every migration.